# using Xpath to scrape inconsistent DOM

Tags: html, dom, xpath, web-scraping

I want to scrape the post name, which for pattern one it's located within a span

[image]

but the forum thread can goes like this (line 7)

[image]

because the thread is a poll.

so in my case I can't target the span (line 8 first picture), I used descendants-or-self but hardly to get it right. What's wrong here?

```
$postTitle = $xpath->query("//tr/td[@class='row1'][3]/div/div[1]//descendant-or-self::text()");
```

Comment: @helderdarocha thx I messed up 2 images, I've updated it. The first image, <span style="color: green">

Comment: What do you want to select? `Salary vs age` and `"    Poll:    "`? The `div` contents?

Comment: 'salary vs age '

and

'/ktars are you really smart as you think?'. They are the forum thread's name

Answer (score 0):

With this expression you will select the first `<a>` in the `<div>` where the text you wish to extract is located:

```
//tr/td[@class='row1'][3]/div/div[1]/a[1]
```

I'm assuming you intend to select *one* element (and not a node-set). For that you can get the string-value of this expression (which will return all the text in the descendant nodes) using `string()` or `normalize-space()` (which trims and removes extra spaces):

```
normalize-space(//tr/td[@class='row1'][3]/div/div[1]/a[1])
```

This will extract `Salary vs age` or `/ktards are you...` depending on the node found.

*If there is more than one match* it will return a collection, which you should iterate over and get the string value of each one individually. Using those functions on a node-set will give you the text in the *first* element, discarding the others.

If you only have to deal with two cases: 1) text inside `a/span`, 2) text inside `a`, you can select the text nodes directly using a *union* (`|`) operator:

```
//tr/td[@class='row1'][3]/div/div[1]/a[1]/text() | //tr/td[@class='row1'][3]/div/div[1]/a[1]/span/text()
```

Comment: how can you know my problem is extra spaces? and how should I query it when I use normalize-space?

Comment: The XPath query returns a *node-set* which may be converted to its *string-value*. You can get the string-value using your host language, but you can also convert it to its string-value using the XPath function `string()`. If you wish to remove extra spaces that frequently appear when you convert nodes to its string value, then you can use `normalize-space()` which, like `string()` also converts the node-set to its string value, but also replaces newlines, multiple spaces and tabs for one space, and trims spaces in the beginning and end.

Comment: what is node-set? can't I just get the value? I cant do postTitle->nodeValue?

Comment: It has the same effect. A `node-set` is a collection type returned in most XPath 1.0 expressions. It's part of the XPath object model. The result tree may be a text type (includes strings, numbers, booleans) or node-set. The *string value* of a node-set is the concatenation of all *descendant* text nodes (which is not the same as `text()` - the text *children* of the node). A node-set may contain more than one element, and you may lose data depending on how you extract data from node-sets that contain multiple elements.

Comment: get the entire set and turn it into string? I don't get you bro. Can u post a solution?

Comment: That's what the solution above is doing. But you don't *need* to use XPath functions `string()` or `normalize-space()`. Use your `nodeValue()` functions. Try the first expression (without these functions). I also added another option (see the last expression).

Comment: I tried to use | but there were blank result. I put it in <li>, some rows are blank.

Comment: This also gives you back all the text contents: `//tr/td[@class='row1'][3]/div/div[1]/a[1]//text()`